# How to redirect old website pages to new website which has same domain but new html page names?

Tags: html, .htaccess, redirect, web

I'm working on a website which has had all it's page names changed from the older version however it still has the same domain name. All I want to do is re-direct the page links on google searches to the domain and/or redirect the pages to their new page named versions.

I know this can be done with a .htaccess file. But I'm not sure how as I have tried and it's not working.

Comment: "I have tried" — **What** have you tried?

Answer (score 0):

To tell google that pages have changed their name you should use 301 redirects.

Here is a nice documentation about howto do those: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectpermanent

Using mod_alias you can also define regex patterns, like for example /(.*)_old.html has to go to /$1_new.html or things like this, by using RedirectMatch.

Make sure that you use permanent redirects, because google pays attention to if you use permanent (301) or just temporary (302) redirects.